# Socket input stream and Unicode

Tags: android, sockets, unicode, inputstream

I try to write an app that sends text from Windows computer to Android cellphone.
The text I send can be in English or Hebrew (for example). The connection is via Socket. The code I use on the Windows side (Visual studio 2012):

```
String buffer = // Some text
// Encode the data string into a byte array.            
byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(buffer + "\n");
// Send the data through the socket.
int bytesSent = socketSender.Send(msg);
```

And on the Android side:

```
//After I establish the Socket
String text = "";
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();    
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
while ((inputText = in.readLine()) != null)
{
     text = inputText;
}
```

All this works perfectly when sending English text.
When I try to send Hebrew text I replace to this line:

```
byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(buffer + "\n");
```

But on the Android side I can't "read" it.
I tried to use `CharsetEncoder` but didn't work (or I did it the wrong way).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the answer is:
on the Windows side:

```
byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(buffer + "\n");
```

And on the Android side:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
```